# opened off the school library; opened to where?

Tags: vocabulary

> The room set aside for the guidance department at Winterdown Comprehensive **opened off the school library**. It had no windows and was lit by a single strip light.
>   (The Casual Vacancy, J. K. Rowling)

When the room is opened off the library, does it mean that the room’s door is opened onto the library - *opened outward*? Or is it contrary - *opened inward*? Or is it quite different from both mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The room set aside for the guidance department at Winterdown Comprehensive opened off the school library. It had no windows and was lit by a single strip light.

Per [Jason Patterson](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/11567/jason-patterson)'s comments, the meaning is

> The room set aside for the guidance department at Winterdown Comprehensive **had its entrance located in the school library**. It had no windows and was lit by a single strip light.

A quote from *"[Walking Tours of Ancient Rome](http://books.google.ru/books?id=6bOLJ3LSRq0C&lpg=PA152&dq=%22open%20off%20of%22&hl=ru&pg=PA152#v=onepage&q=%22open%20off%20of%22&f=false)":*

> Library: Two rooms **open off of the library** and are named for their decorative schemes, the Room of the Mausoleum of Hadrian, and the Room of the Festoons.

A quote from "*[Building Regulations Explained](http://books.google.ru/books?id=uZNFAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA587&dq=%22open%20off%20of%22&hl=ru&pg=PA587#v=onepage&q=%22open%20off%20of%22&f=false)*":

> The three rooms will **open off of** a small landing 1.6 m×1.4m.

To illustrate the last quote: a small landing with three rooms *opening off (of) it*:

[image]

Comment: This isn't quite the right sense of it; if Room A **opens off of** Room B, then Room A's entrance is *in* Room B.  It would make more sense if we used "opens from," but we don't.

Comment: Wow, great, thank you, @JasonPatterson! I did not know that. Will scrap my answer.

Comment: That explains why the room in the example has no windows; it isn't a normal room built along an outside wall.  It's more like a giant closet.

Comment: This is a phrase you see a lot in real estate listings, when they are trying to give you a sense of the layout of the house.  You could have a porch that opens off of a kitchen, or a bedroom that opens off of the upstairs hallway.

Comment: Thanks, @JasonPatterson! Is the use of the "of" after "off" optional? J.K. omits it. And what's the grammatical role of **off**, I wonder. Is it an adverb or a preposition?

Comment: Yes, the "of" is optional.  Both versions are commonly used in AmE (I don't know about British English usage with this at all.)  I'm no grammarian, but I believe it is still acting as a preposition.  It always has an object, and it is describing the position of one location with respect to another.  It's more or less synonymous with "from," but we don't say that a room opens from another room.  It would be understood, but it's not idiomatic.